# graphql_flutter mutation query expects return statement - not sure how to add it

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql-flutter

The mutation query on the builder method is expecting a return statement, which I am not sure where and how to add to the below code. I believe the mutation query should return a pass or fail for the operation.

I have been trying to figure this out for the past few days. I still haven't got a clue on what is wrong.

I have this method which is called on the onCompleted callback when the user fills in the one time code.

createUser Mutation Query -

```
class GraphQlMutations {
  final String createUser = r'''
  mutation createUser($uid: ID!, $fullname: String!, $phone: String!, $photourl: String, $createdtime: String){
    createUser(uid: $uid, fullname: $fullname, phone: $phone, photourl: $photourl, createdtime: $createdtime){
      uid
      fullname
      phone
      photourl
      createdtime
    }
  }
''';
}

void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(
      PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
    setState(() {
      showLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      setState(() {
        showLoading = false;
      });
      final authCredential =
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
      User? user = authCredential.user;
      print(user);
      if (authCredential.user != null) {
        Mutation(
          options: MutationOptions(
              document: gql(GraphQlMutations().createUser),
              onCompleted: (dynamic resultData) {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('New user added')));
              }),
          builder: (RunMutation createUser, QueryResult? result) {
            if (user != null) {
              final DateTime? createdTime = user.metadata.creationTime;
              final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
              final String userCreatedTime = formatter.format(createdTime!);
              try {
                createUser({
                  'uid': user.uid,
                  'fullname': _fullname.text,
                  'phone': user.phoneNumber,
                  'photourl': 'https://www.bol.com',
                  'createdtime': userCreatedTime,
                });
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Conversations()));
              } catch (e) {}
            }
          },
        );
      }
    } 
  }
```

Vscode points out an error on the builder method which exactly says -

**The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the**

Somebody with expertise in graphq_flutter please chime in to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check your mutation query in graphql console because mutation query require field returning or affected_rows as show in image [image: graphql mutation query]

and if you are running sound null safety then you should also consider that any of your fields(uid, fullname, phone,...) aren't retuning null.

and can you provide more detail on `createUser` if problem not resolve

Comment: hello ruchit, i have added my mutation query, my query doesn't return any null values. Also I have tried the query in graphiql, it works.